# Export makefile loop index as env var

Tags: makefile

I have a loop in makefile and I want to export the loop index as env var but it does not work. Any help is appreciated Thanks.

```
      define set_env_var
          $(eval export $(1)=$(2))
       endef

     for i in $(FILES); do \
            $(call set_env_var, name, echo $$i) \
            echo ${name} ;\
    done
```

Comment: This is not a Make loop, but a shell loop. Do you understand how Make commands? It expands `$(...)` in the entire recipe, then runs the commands in the shell.

Comment: Thanks! I now not sure I understand :-( how can I do that? I actually want to use the index in a sed command but referring to the index $$i  shows nothing. Thanks

Comment: Makefiles are not shell scripts and make is not a shell.  Makefiles can _contain_ shell scripts and make can _invoke_ a shell.  But while the shell is running, it can't communicate back and forth interactively with make.  So loop variables in a shell loop like `for` cannot be sent back to make.  Make will fully expand the entire recipe FIRST, then the result of all the expansion is sent to the shell and the shell runs it, then the shell exits with a single exit code and make checks it to see if it succeeded or not.  So what you have asked to do here is impossible.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me.  Why don't you edit your question and ask about what you really want to do, with a useful example (include the complete rule, not just the recipe) then we can help you with that, instead of asking for something else that's not really want you want to do anyway.